# How can I convert a string to enum in typescript 2.9.1?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum definition like this:

```
export enum ConfirmActionKeys {
    yes = 'yes',
    no = 'no',
    ok = 'ok',
    cancel = 'cancel'
  }
```

I get a string variable which has the value of each member in ConfirmActionKeys but how can I make it to be a type of `ConfirmActionKeys`? Below is the code:

```
function sayHi(key: ConfirmActionKeys) {
}

const key = "ok";
sayHi(...); // how can I call sayHi method here
```

I have tried `sayHi(ConfirmActionKeys[key])` but it complains that `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`.  Is there a method like `valueOf` in Java to do that?

Comment: works in TS 3.0.1

Comment: I am using 2.9.1

Comment: from my experience, it's easier to just use string literals as enums anyway

Answer (score 0):

In TS 2.9.1, it can be solved by define the parameter type as below:

```
const key: ConfirmActionKeys.yes | ConfirmActionKeys.no | ConfirmActionKeys.cancel | ConfirmActionKeys.ok = "ok";
sayHi(key);
```